# Java save alphabet to array

Tags: java

I try save alphabet A-Z to my array, but I don't understand, why I get only this output: Z.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char []tab = new char[25];

        for (int i = 0; i<25; i++) {
            for (int j=65; j<91; j++) {
                tab[i] = (char)j;
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
            System.out.println(tab[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's because of the inner loop which will set every element of `tab` to `(char)90`. Try `tab[i] = 65 + i;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loop, try this:

```
char[] tab = new char[26];
for (int i = 0, j = 65; j < 91; j++, i++) {
  tab[i] = (char) j;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  System.out.println(tab[i]);
}
```

Also, array size should be 26 not 25.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is wrong.

Check this simpler solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   char []tab = new char[25];

   for (int i = 0; i<25; i++) {
            tab[i] = (char)(i+65);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        System.out.println(tab[i]);
    }
}
```

Your code puts all the letters from A to Z in each slot of the tab array, when executing the 'j' loop, that's why you have only Zs.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see how your code works:

```
for (int i = 0; i<25; i++) {       //1
    for (int j=65; j<91; j++) {    //2
        tab[i] = (char)j;          //3
    }                              //4
}                                  //5
```

1) Outer loop sets `i=0`,
2) Inner loop sets `j=65`
3) `(char)65` represents `'A'` ant is placed in `tab[0]`
2) Inner loop sets `j=66`
3) `(char)66` represents `'B'` and is also placed in `tab[0]`

Here you should notice the problem, which is that inner loop is working on **same `i`**, so while iterating over A...Z it is modifying same array location, which means that location will hold last value placed there, which is `'Z'`.
<sub>*(BTW `i<25` should be `i<26`)*</sub>

#### Possible solution

don't use inner loop, you can calculate value which should be placed at index by adding `i` to `65` which in Unicode Table is codepoint of `'A'`

```
for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
    tab[i] = (char)(65+i);
```

BTW you can farther improve readability of this code by avoiding magic numbers (more info: [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)). So this code can be rewritten into something like:

```
int amountOfLetters = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
char[] tab = new char[amountOfLetters];

int i = 0;
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
    tab[i++] = ch;
}

System.out.println(new String(tab));
```

Comment: You can get rid of i: tab[(int)ch - 'A'] = ch

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard True, but that would make code less readable (at least IMO) which I want to avoid.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's acceptable since you already do 'A' + 1 at the beginning. But, you are right it's less readable.